# Membrane material in Cycles?

Tags: materials

I'm using Blender Cycles to model a strand of DNA. Ideally, I'd like to make certain parts of the model look like they're encased in a clear, sticky membrane, like this:

[image: Something like the membrane in this render by Alexey Kashpersky]

How would I make this material with the Cycles Node Editor?

Comment: I find this site has a lot of great ideas on material creation, and like the glass one here: http://www.chocofur.com/6-shadersamptextures.html as a starting point for resins... Would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less something like that ?

[image]

The membrane is simply a mix between glass and glossy and a manual adjustment of a fresnel node to handle the mix factor.

[image]

The DNA is base on the same principle, but with diffuse and emission :

[image]

But for the sticky effect this is mainly a displacement texture (a cloud texture) on the membrane :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a shell with the glas material and under it a volume material. If you need some light to the scene can you ty to use the emission shadder with the volume shadder.